# Avada Live Builder Display doesn't match actual site

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make the main menu of the site be on one row, but it wraps to a second row, even though I set No Wrap. In the Live Builder, it shows it working exactly how I want it to:
[image]

The live site malfunctions in the way described above:
[image]

How should I go about fixing this? What other information do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just had to change the site width so the menu fit in the whole view.